# PHPMailer SMTP connect() error with GMAIL ! ( php_openssl and php_smtp extensions are enabled)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';


    $mail->Username = "my gmail email id";
    $mail->Password = "my gmail password";

    $mail->IsHTML(true); 

    $mail->From = "sender@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Sender name";

    $mail->addAddress("receiver@gmail.com","Receiver");

    $mail->Subject = "Testing PHPMailer with localhost";
    $mail->Body = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly.";

    if(!$mail->Send())
        echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    else
        echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Executing this script shows : PHPMailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
1. **php_openssl and php_smtp extensions are enabled.**
2. **IMAP is enabled in GMAIL SETTINGS**

Comment: Try 'tls' instead of 'ssl' with port 587

Comment: I tried but still the same error .

Comment: set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;` to get more feedback on errors

Comment: there is a big list of errors! it's difficult to figure out what is the error.

Comment: That's because `SMTPDebug = 4` is very verbose; `SMTPDebug = 2` is enough. Why didn't you follow the gmail example provided with PHPMailer and read the troubleshooting docs that the error message points you to? (If you didn't see a link, it means you're running an old, vulnerable version of PHPMailer, so you should update).

Answer (score 0):

turn on less secure app in your google account setting..
ref:: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229

This Code is working for me

```
 $sender_email='test@gmail.com';
        $receiver_email='test@gamil.com';
        $username='username';

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'test@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '#####';

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        // Sender email address
        $this->email->from($sender_email, $username);
        // Receiver email address
        $this->email->to($receiver_email);
        // Subject of email
        $this->email->subject('Testing');
        // Message in email
        $this->email->message('this is testing mail');
        $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Log in your gamil account than access this link . https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: I am going to check it out

Comment: " Account access enabled " everything seems to be fine !